Visual Studio Code cannot find one of my modules, but cmd can find it without issue using the same methods
When using a venv I cannot find my neat module. This image shows that I have installed the module, have selected the right venv and it still doesn't work. This image shows that attempting the same in a command prompt as the vscode terminal gives no issue. The issue first showed up using the debugger, but using the terminal it looks more widespread than that.vscode
I have tried reloading the VSCode window as recommended here, doing a full PC restart, both manually activating the venv using venv\script\activate and trusting the VSCode interpreter selector to use it properly. I have tried manually entering the filepath to the interpreter just in case. I have tried selecting another interpreter and reselecting the correct one as suggested here
